# Run Numbers '09 (v 2.3) under Catalina or later

Tags: catalina, mojave, numbers, iwork

I vastly prefer running the older Numbers for Mac (Numbers '09). I've kept my iMac running Mojave for this reason. But I'd like to upgrade my OS. What (if any) is the best way of running Numbers '09 under Catalina, Big Sur or later?

(Dual-booting isn't a great solution as I use Numbers all the time. I know I can upgrade the sheets to the new Numbers, but it's the GUI of the older one I prefer.)